# Multiple implementations of Dependency Injection - ASP.NET Core

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an interface `IRepository<TEntity>`, and a generic repository `Repository<TEntity, TContext>`. `GameRepository` and `UserRepository` are extended from `Repository<TEntity, TContext>`. Instead of adding the repositories manually, I want to do it in one line. I've tried the one-line solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55885758/11557167), but it doesn't seem to work in my case.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            );

            services.AddScoped<GameRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<UserRepository>();
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use just one line to register GameRepository and UserRepository?  In my opinion, we couldn't do that, since the GameRepository  and UserRepository is different class. We couldn't use DI to new two different class in your services.

Comment: What are the other solutions that can do the similar thing?

Answer (score 0):

> What are the other solutions that can do the similar thing?

As far as I know, there is no way to do similar thing, if you still want to use one line, I suggest you could consider create a service connection extension method.

You could create a ServicesConfiguration class like below:

```
public static class ServicesConfiguration
{
    public static void AddCustomServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<GameRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<UserRepository>();
    }
}
```

Then you could register this service by using just one line:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCustomServices();
}
```